# How to use flatbuffers `key` attribute to simulate HashMap with flatbuffers in Rust?

Tags: dictionary, rust, ordereddictionary, flatbuffers

I need to create a `string` to `string` map with [flatbuffers](https://docs.rs/crate/flatbuffers/0.8.3) in Rust similar to:

```
pub struct HashMapIndex {
    keyword_by_filter: HashMap<String, String> // filter text -> keyword
}
```

I've found some `key` flatbuffers [attribute](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_writing_schema.html) that can be put on array item, but it seems to be neither documented nor shown in samples:

> Can be used for in-place binary search

```
table KeywordToFilters {
  filter_text: string (key);
  keyword: string;
}

table Index {
  map: [KeywordToFilters];
}
```

How can i use it (get value by key)? The problem is that no map-like methods are generated - it's just a vector:

```
pub map: Option<flatbuffers::WIPOffset<flatbuffers::Vector<'a , flatbuffers::ForwardsUOffset<KeywordToFilters<'a >>>>>,
```

Is there more efficient way to have a map with flatbuffers in Rust?

PS. flatbuffers crate version is 0.8.3

Comment: I guess there is not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51437592/how-to-store-dictionariesmap-in-flatbuffer-in-java

Comment: it's about Java, i guess the generated file can be different a lot

Comment: I think there is no concept of hashmap in flatbuffers, that not surprising hashmap is not very memory efficient to parse and so I guess google want people to use vector putting the key and the value in one item, but that just supposition

Comment: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/5713 as I said

Comment: Yup, not implemented yet.

Comment: @Aardappel Please convert to the answer to be accepted